# How to delete multiple fields in an attribute table?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes

Is there a way to select multiple fields in an attribute table and delete them together in Arcmap without writing the script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily do it two different ways without writing a script:

1. Use the [Delete Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004n000000) tool in Data Management Tools. On a single table you can select all Fields you want to Drop (see picture below). For multiple fields in multiple tables you can use [Batch Processing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000). You would need to create a row for each field you want to delete.

[image: Image of the Delete Field Tool]

2. Install the [Xtools Pro](http://www.xtoolspro.com/) extension, its Multi Delete Fields tool will do this. Xtools requires registration after 14 days, when you register you can either pay to get the full suite of tools or you can register for free and use its free tools indefinitely. Most of the tools in the extension (including the Multi Delete Fields one) are free.

Answer (score 17):

The Delete Field tool might be what you're looking for. You just open the tool, tick the checkboxes for any fields you want to delete and then click OK to run it.

[image]